# Where to find + how to install themes for TortoiseHg (W10)?

Tags: themes, tortoisehg

I'm hoping to install a dark theme for TortoiseHg on my W10 computer (similar to the dark theme in VS2015 to reduce eyestrain from looking at it all day) but there's so little documentation out there that I'm not clear if it's even possible.

Every example I've come across seems to imply that it's only possible when running Linux/Ubuntu, and even then it's not super clear what theme types I should be looking for (GTK2?, KDE?).

All that the TortoiseHg mentions is at the following link (under "How to I change GTK themes?"): http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/faq.html.

That said, any specific sites or themes that have a good selection? To keep it objective, I am looking for something as close to the VisualStudio 2015 dark theme as possible.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Late answer, but still relevant.*

TortoiseHg do not have any theming possibilities. To make most of THG dark, You have to switch Windows 10 theme to dark (or dark high contrast for previous Windowses).

Unfortunately, You can expect many bugs which are tracked in this issue:
https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues/810